# Localization for the words "minutes" and "seconds" in countDownTimerLabel

Tags: swift, timer, localization, countdowntimer

I localised almost all labels and buttons. However, when I localise my timerLabel, the words "min" and "sec" are not translated in other language. Here's the timer function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQdZd.png)

In order to localise countDownLabel, I used this localisation method below.

```
func setUpTranslation() {

countDownLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("CountDown", comment: "")

}
```

I tried to set "CountDown" key for the countDownLabel in Localizable.strings(Spanish) like these below one by one. But they didn't work.

"CountDown" = "(%d)min(%d)seg"

"CountDown" = "(minutes)min(seconds)seg"

"CountDown" = "%dmin%dseg"

"CountDown" = "\(%d)min\(%d)seg"

Would you tell me whether there is any other sign that I need to add to successfully translate those words or not?

Comment: You should consider using `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and your quick response. I solved the problem. Arigato-gozaimasu!